# how to round timestamp to day in HIVE?

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have a string value like `'2020-10-01T02:02:50.918+03:00'`. How can I get value like this: `2020-10-01 00:00:00.000` in timestamp datatype in Hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substr to get yyyy-MM-dd, then use timestamp construct.

Demo:

```
select timestamp(substr('2020-10-01T02:02:50.918+03:00',1,10))
```

Result:

```
2020-10-01 00:00:00.0
```